# how to find recent record of record matching particular criteria

Tags: node.js, mongoose

```
    {
"_id" : ObjectId("5514ecc73910d3e808b9417c"),
"endingReciptBookNumber" : 2999,
"startingReciptBookNumber" : 2900,
"User" : 8,
"allRecipt" : [ 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 2999,
        "amount" : 24124,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5514ecc73910d3e808b94180")
    }, 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 100,
        "amount" : 2414,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5514ecc73910d3e808b9417f")
    }, 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 101,
        "amount" : 242,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5514ecc73910d3e808b9417e")
    }, 
    {
        "recipt_Number" : 102,
        "amount" : 2424,
        "_id" : ObjectId("5514ecc73910d3e808b9417d")
    }
],
"__v" : 0
```

}

I have many documents like this in a collection in mongoose .I want to find a latest entered recipt_Number for a particular user. like in this case it should give me 102 as answer.

Comment: Object ID's contain timestamps, you can use that to search for the latest timestamp

Comment: Recipt.aggregate([
   {$match: {'User': +req.params.name}},
   {$sort:{timestamp : -1}},
   {$limit: 1}    
  ], function (err, result){
   if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
   }
   console.log(result);
   res.json(result);
  }); ----- i used this but it is giving the first entered record for that user but i want to find the last eneterd record

Comment: Did you try unwind allReceipt array and and sort by _id then push grouped new document?

Comment: hey i found solution by myself here it is: Recipt.aggregate([
   {$match: {'User': +req.params.name}},
   {$sort:{'allRecipt._id' : -1}},
   {$limit: 1}    
  ], function (err, result){
   if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
   }
   console.log(result);
   res.json(result);
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have also attached snippet of lines of code. Its also a way to get same result.

```
db.topics.find( {'User': 8}, { 'allRecipt': { $slice: -1 },'startingReciptBookNumber':0,'endingReciptBookNumber':0,'User':0,'_id':0,'__v':0 } )
```

query result like below

```
{
    "allRecipt" : [ 
        {
            "recipt_Number" : 102,
            "amount" : 2424,
            "_id" : ObjectId("5514ecc73910d3e808b9417d")
        }
    ]
}
```

Though query won't give any single number in result but it will give desired outcome through result.allRecipt.0.recipt_Number, Your desired number will always get into in 0 index. I think this is your desired number.

Here [$slice](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) make a difference.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging the answer.. :)